# Building footprint polygon from LoD1 CityGML 2.0 using R and sf?

Tags: r, sf, citygml

I have LoD1 building data from a federal agency in Germany in the `CityGML` format. I would like to import and strip the data into `R` to get only the footprint of the buildings and an attribut about the height. In case of building parts with different heights I would ideally get a the building footprint with multiple height fields (or a list containing the different height information). `sf` let's me import the data but I only partially gives the expected result: While it works for some buildings, for other building only a part is imported. I included a sample from the data with one building where the import works just fine and the other where only parts of building are imported. I noticed that the structure of the `cityObjectMember` from the first `bldg:Building` is different and the `gml:id` for this building is empty.  Although I guess this is the reason why it's not imported correctly but I was wondering if this is because the data is corrupted or if there is a logic behind this.

I have no experience with CityGML but I also couldn't find tutorials on how to work with CityGML in `R` or any other editor that would allow for anything beyon visualization.

How do I import and strip CityGML data in R?

Here's what I've tried so far:

[Test data with two buildings](https://we.tl/t-muj4ZcUkWO)

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

#Import buildings
buildings = read_sf("test_building.xml")

# First building (with empty gml_id) not correctly imported
# Only spatial information for a part of the building is imported 
plot(st_geometry(building[1,]))

#Second building (with gml_id==DENILD4300007ABe) works fine 
plot(st_geometry(building[2,]))
```

Comment: Not 100 % sure, but from my point of view reading these file with `sf` fails because there is no GMLAS driver included, c.f. `sf::st_drivers()`. `ogrinfo` and `ogr2ogr` with explicit GMLAS works just fine (c.f. [here](https://3d.bk.tudelft.nl/svitalis/citygml/gdal/2017/07/24/messing-around-with-citygml-on-gdal-2.2.html)) on the other hand.

Answer (score 1):

I am working with the same data facing the exactly same problem. I found it easier to use the following way to read the data:

```
library(rgdal)

path <- 'path/to/your/data'

BE <- readOGR(file.path(path, "LoD1_372_5804_2.xml"), encoding = 'UTF-8')

head(BE@data[, grep('measuredHeight', names(BE@data))])
```

You can see that the part read as a list by `sf` is separated into columns using `rgdal`. Here the ‘regular’ variable `measuredHeight` is now named `measuredHeight_` with missing values, wherever the information is stored in the `measuredHeight1`, … , `measuredHeight5` (in this case) variables.

Comment: After having tried several ways to import these CityGML files, I wanted to note that `rgdal::readOGR()` also seems to fail with `Multiple incompatible geometries: wkbMultiPoint: 198; NA: 4` - probably also due to the missing GMLAS driver, c.f. `rgdal::ogrDrivers()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with R, and have not worked with `sf`.

The CityGML format is also more complex than you described. A building has many `surfaces`, and a `surface` has its own attributes including a polygon which would probably be what you are looking for.

Geometries in CityGML are at the finest level stored as polygons. Try looking for tags with `<gml:posList srsDimension="3">` in your CityGML file, you will probably find many polygons. Every line in the `<gml:posList srsDimension="3">` tag is a list of vertices. I have not worked with LoD1 data, but it's likely that it will have the format of `x0 y0 x1 y1 x2 y2` if it's a 2D triangle. For example, this is what a polygon looks like in my CityGML LoD2 file:

```
<gml:posList srsDimension="3">317107.971596384 79697.4604185931 15.3638404876802 317107.971596384 79697.4604185931 27.0662941325891 317107.028896385 79697.6447185921 27.0662941325891 317107.028896385 79697.6447185921 15.3638404876802 317107.971596384 79697.4604185931 15.3638404876802</gml:posList>
```

So, sounds like you want to extract multiple Polygons for a single building, as you say a building can have many footprints. If you are open to other tools, [here](https://github.com/yuqli/gml2obj) is a Python tool I wrote that extract polygons and store as `.obj` mesh files, which You can easily extract polygons from.

You can also check out a data warehousing software called FME, which can also be used to extract geometries from CityGML files. I have a blog post [here](http://yuqli.com/?p=2982) describing how, you can look at section 2 only.

After acquiring building meshes, you can look up how to import geometries into R. `.obj` is a very common format for 3D data. All my experience are from handling 3D data only, but should be applicable to 2D too.

[Another](https://github.com/tudelft3d/CityGML2OBJs) useful tool for parsing cityGML.

Finally, if you are familiar with `.xml` files, you can also try parsing the polygons yourself. As mentioned all geometries are stored in the tag `<gml:posList srsDimension="3">`, as I have observed.

Good luck!